# http://localhost:3000/api/users net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, api, express

I can login to my app and it shows that login is successful, however when I refresh page it gives this error

```
http://localhost:3000/api/users net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I'm using Node.js with Angular on front. Also using JWT for tokens.

My backend app.js:

```
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(cookieParser());

mongoose.connect(config.database);

app.use(cors({origin: "http://localhost:8000",credentials: true }));

app.use('/api/upload/single', expressJWT({secret: config.secret}));



app.use(function (error, request, response, next) {   if (error.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
    response.status(401).json({message: 'You need an authorization token to view this page.'});   } });

// MULTER var s3config = require('./config/s3'); var upload = multer({ storage: s3({
    dirname: s3config.dirname,
    bucket: s3config.bucket,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_SECRET,
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: s3config.region,
    contentType: function(req, file, next) {
      next(null, file.mimetype);
    },
    filename: function(req, file, next) {
      var ext = '.' + file.originalname.split('.').splice(-1)[0];
      var filename = uuid.v1() + ext;
      next(null, filename);
    }   }) });

// UPLOAD SINGLE FILE app.post('/api/upload/single', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {   var clothing_1 = {
    type: req.body.type,
    image: req.file.key   };   console.log(req.body);   // get the user model User.findOne({ id: req.user._id })   User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id }, {}, { new: true }, function(err, user){
    user.clothing.push(clothing_1);
    // save this user
    user.save(function(err, user){
      if(err) return res.status(401).send({ message: 'your error:' + err });
      else return res.json({ user: user })
    });   });

}); // app.get('api/users', usersController.showUser); app.use('/api', routes);

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Please post your server side code to help us troubleshoot.  Otherwise this is impossible to answer.

Comment: The ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error indicates that it is not running, so probably has crashed. Put in some logging or use node-inspector to debug to see what is causing the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out was simply a matter of not putting the right controller on my Angular states.